# I have 3 errors:expected a ")" , expected an expression, argument of type long is incompatible with parameter of type U32

Tags: c++, c, opencv

```
/*******************************************************************/
#define cdisp(a, src, col);
#define FL_wpset_U8 256;
/*******************************************************************/
void main(void)
{
    int posx= 100, posy=100, dx=300, dy=300; 
    long length=5000; 
    int threshold=125; 
    int lx, x0=0, y0=0;
    int res1=0,res2=0, *rlc, *input, i;
    long dest1,dest2,desttemp, addr;
    char c;
    image Area, Ovl;





    ScrSetLogPage((int)ScrGetPhysPage);
    OvlSetLogPage((int)OvlGetPhysPage);

    OvlClearAll;

    set_ovlmask(255);

    ImageAssign(&Area,ScrByteAddr(posx,posy), dx, dy, ScrGetPitch);

    ImageAssign(&Ovl,OvlBitAddr(posx,posy), dx, dy, OvlGetPitch);


    frameo(&Ovl);




    vmode(vmOvlLive);
    /* follow contour */
    dest1=DRAMWordMalloc((long)length);
    dest2=DRAMWordMalloc((long)length);
```

The 2 errors are in the line `frameo(&Ovl)` (expected a ")" , expected an expression).

```
desttemp = dest1;
res1 = contour8(&Area,x0,y0,~2,threshold,length,&desttemp);
```

The last error is in the last line (argument of type long is incompatible with parameter of type U32). The function signature of contour8 is `I32 contour8(image *a, I32 x0, I32 y0, I32 dir, I32 thr, U32 lng, U32 **dst)`.
I don't know how to solve it ,thanks in advance.

Comment: `main` is required to have an `int` return type. As for your last error, a single pointer is not a double pointer.

Comment: Please, be aware, that the place where the missing ) are reported is way after the place, where the error is.

Comment: What is `OvlClearAll;`? Function calls in C must have `()`. If you leave out the `()` you get a function pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the `;` from defines.

Answer (score 5):

You almost *certainly* don't want those semicolons at the end of your `#define` lines.
 Using them will most likely inject the statement separator into the middle of expressions.